# StackOverflowError when calling method of subclass object?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, stack-overflow

Executing the Test class gives a StackOverFlow error :(

Parent class :

```
package Pack;

public class Alpha {
  protected void sayHi() {
    System.out.println("Hi...from Alpha");
  }
}
```

Child class :

```
import Pack.Alpha;

public class AlphaSub extends Alpha {
  AlphaSub sb=new AlphaSub() ;

  void hi() {
    sb.sayHi() ;

  }
}
```

Test class :

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    AlphaSub ob=new AlphaSub() ;
    ob.hi() ;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stackoverflow has nothing to do with the inheritance, but with this line (inside `AlphaSub`):

```
AlphaSub sb=new AlphaSub() ;
```

You are creating a new `AlphaSub` instance inside your `AlphaSub`, which causes an endleess loop. I assume you don't even make it to the `ob.hi()` line in your test

Comment: I apologize for linking this with inheritance. i got it .. its due to instance creation inside its own class (sub-class).